# SwiftUI - Toggle has to be tapped twice to trigger inside a List or Form

Tags: swift, list, swiftui, toggle

When the first launch of the app, I need to tap the toggle twice before it can change its state. This happens every first launch of the app.

If I click anywhere on the screen before clicking on the toggle button and then click the button, only need to click the toggle once.

Here's a simple reproducable example of the problem:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showView = false

    var body: some View {
        List() {
            Section {
                Toggle("Show advanced options", isOn: $showView)
                Text("showView is \(showView ? 1 : 0)")
           }
        }
    }
}
```

When first click any position of the screen ,the console will print bellow debug info, Then I can click the toggle once to trigger.

```
2023-07-15 17:27:59.417435+0800 Clocks[13208:1708660] Successfully load keyboard extensions
2023-07-15 17:28:00.920630+0800 Clocks[13208:1708660] invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' provided to CFRunLoopRunSpecific - break on _CFRunLoopError_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug. This message will only appear once per execution
```

Comment: I was able to reproduce this once, and I couldn't reproduce it again. How do you do a *second* "first launch"? I deleted the app and ran again but couldn't reproduce.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this bug with Xcode 14.3 on a physical iPhone 14. I bet you're on Xcode 14.3.1? Also, don't worry about the second line of the console, it always happens with toggles.

Comment: It has been successful for me. Could you please provide further details? I've attempted this scenario numerous times and it consistently produces positive results.

Comment: When click run button in Xcode. App launch in simulator, do not click other postion in App. Just click the toggle. The first click have no effect, and xcode will print "Successfully load keyboard extensions". Then next click of toggle will take effect.

Comment: This seems like an Xcode debugger thing. When I build & run with Xcode I see the issue. But if I then kill the app (disconnecting the debugger) and tap the app icon on my physical device to open the app again, I don't see the issue. My form (with toggle inside) was being presented in a sheet, not sure if that makes a difference.